# html "a" align in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The "login" part is not aligned to the right, I used the "text-align" in CSS on the "a" tag, but it is stil not aligned, what am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">    <a href="http://cp.x10host.com/countdowns/home/"> <img class="header" src="title.jpg"> </a>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="underline">
            <img class="underline" src="ul.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="topBar">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Home </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Community </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Your Countdowns </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Explore </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="login" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Login </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="underline" src="ul.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 a.login{font-size:30px; text-align:right; text-decoration: none; color:#ffffff;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Now deeming this question "unanswered", as my problem was not solved. This is my first time using Stack Overflow. Did not get a good impression*

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add display:block to a.login

Comment: I made a jsfiddle to figure it out:  http://jsfiddle.net/briggs_w/2kebh18n/1/ ...and this definitely works.  But why?

Answer (score 1):

Element `<a>` is an `inline` element so it will not work with `text-align`. You need to apply `text-align` to parent element to indicated that you want all inline elements inside to be aligned to this side.

You can add `text-align` to `<td>` element (eg. `td {text-align:right}`).

PS. Why you are using `<font>`? It's old element which should be abandoned a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using text-align to move right side, you could add 
margin-left.

a.login {

```css
a.login {
margin-left: 129px;
font-size: 30px;
/* text-align: right; */
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">    <a href="http://cp.x10host.com/countdowns/home/"> <img class="header" src="title.jpg"> </a>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="underline">
            <img class="underline" src="ul.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="topBar">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" 

onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Home </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" 

onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Community </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" 

onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Your Countdowns </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="topBar" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" 

onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Explore </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                    <td> <a class="login" href=""> <font onmouseover="this.color='#000000'" 

onmouseout="this.color='#ffffff'"> Login </font> </a> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="underline" src="ul.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```